# How to return a list instead of string from a class by default?

Tags: python, class

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.message

print A("Hello")
```

The above code prints prints "Hello", as a string is returned.
But I want to return a list by default. Like if I write :

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

    def __repr__(self):
        mylist = [self.message]
        return mylist

print A("Hello")
```

The above code gives an error **TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type list)**

I **cannot create an object of the class**, as i need to handle this as an **exception**. like:

```
try:
    #some code which passes parameters to constructor of A if this fails.
except A as e:
    #here I want e as a list instead of string.
```

Is there any way to return a list ?

Comment: You can do `mylist = []` and then `mylist.append(self.message)`

Comment: `__repr__` and `__str__` are supposed to return strings. What are you trying to do that requires you to return something other than a string from `__repr__`?

Answer (score 4):

[`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) and [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) methods must return strings. You have to make a custom getter function.

For instance:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

    def get_message_as_list(self):
        return [self.message]

my_object = A("Hello")
print(my_object.get_message_as_list())
```

As jonrsharpe said, you can't really use a magic (double underscored) method for this.

Comment: That's what I wanted to ask, how do I write that custom getter function ?

Comment: @user3787291 You cannot create an instance of that class, since the __repr__ magic method does not return a string. Maybe I did not understand your question?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad idea. `__repr__` should always return a str because it gets used by lots of internals (like you see here in `print`). For info read on: [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**repr**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

Comment: I am aware that `__repr__` should return string only. So, is there an alternative of `__repr__` which can return list ?

Comment: @user3787291 you can write **literally any method you like** and make it return a list, but if you're using `__magicmethods__` stick to the [documented interfaces](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). As there aren't that many cases where you'd want any arbitrary class to become a list, there's no `__list__` method. If you want `A` to *"quack like"* a list, see [`Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea just for fun. I am using the **call** for returning a non-string output. In the example below, a tuple.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __add__(self, other):
        new_x = self.x + other.x
        new_y = self.y + other.y
        return MyClass(new_x, new_y)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "({},{})".format(self.x, self.y)
    def __call__(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> m1 = MyClass(10, 20)
>>> m1
(10,20)
>>> m1()
(10, 20)
>>> type(m1())
<type 'tuple'>
```